# "Error CS0118: 'field' used as a 'type'" with a Type field

Tags: c#, casting

I'm writing a class that holds a variable of any type. To do so, I store both the variable (as an `object` reference) and its `Type`. When I try to cast the `object` back to the correct type, though, I get error CS0118, because I'm using a field (which is of type `Type`) as a type.

Here is my class:

```
public class Node
{
    Type m_oType = null;
    public Type Type 
    { 
        get { return m_oType; }
        set { m_oType = value; }
    }

    object m_oValue = null;
    public object Value
    {
        get { return m_oValue; }
        set
        {
            if (m_oValue == null)
            {
                if (value is m_oType) // ERROR CS0118
                {
                    m_oValue = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to search online for a way to do this (i.e., using cast operators, `as` and `is`), but I keep getting the same basic tutorials about casting variables. Can someone give me a pointer as to how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: It seems that someone has not heard of generics.

Comment: Chaos, I can't use generics, because I need to manage many `Node` objects without knowing what type of variable they contain (without any guarantee that they're all the same type).

Comment: Sorry for being presumptuous, it's just that my brain automatically translated that code to generics.

Comment: No problem, it would have been a good solution if not for that constraint I had - and I didn't mention it, so... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want something like this (but read on):

```
if (m_oType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))
```

Note that we're calling it *on* `m_oType`, not passing `m_oType` *to* it. From the docs on [`IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx)'s return value, where `c` is the parameter:

> true if c and the current Type represent the same type, or if the current Type is in the inheritance hierarchy of c, or if the current Type is an interface that c implements, or if c is a generic type parameter and the current Type represents one of the constraints of c.

For example, `typeof(object).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string))` returns `true` because `object` is in the inheritance hierarchy of `string`.

EDIT: As noted, that will break if either `m_oType` is null or `value` is null. We can get around `value` being `null` easily enough, but it's not clear what you'd expect it to do if `m_oType` is null. Perhaps you should prevent that in the setter for the `Type` property (and the constructor)? Then use either:

```
// This will always store a null
if (value == null || m_oType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))

// This will never store a null
if (value != null && m_oType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))
```

Comment: @ChaosPandion: True. Will fix.

Comment: Thanks Jon! This seems to address the `is` question just as I need. Chaos is also very precise in noting the `null` vulnerability - of course what you see above is a proof of concept, actual code includes all kinds of checks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
if (m_oType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))
```

But I'm pretty sure you should have a look at Generics.

```
public class Node<T>
{
    T m_oValue = null;
    public T Value
    {
        get { return m_oValue; }
        set
        {
            if (m_oValue == null)
            {
                m_oValue = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Albin, but this is not really what I need. I need to make lists of `Node`s and to handle them without knowing what type `T` is. As far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong), I can't collect a `Node<string>` together with a `Node<int>`.

Comment: @Simone, it is possible if you inherit from a common interface `class Node<T> : INode`, then you can have a collection of `INode`, but if you have different types in your collection generics might not be the best way after all.